# Protractor Selenium error: Java heap space

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, selenium, protractor

I am trying to run some UI performance tests using **Node**, **Protractor**, **Protractor-perf** (https://github.com/axemclion/protractor-perf) and **Selenium (standalone)**. One of my main issues with this is that I sometimes receive a 'Java heap space' error message.

I have tried increasing the Selenium heap size via the protractor config file, but I still receive the error. It might be that the heap size has been specified incorrectly, but I haven't found an example that illustrates how to properly set this Java parameter. So, my question is: is there a way to circumvent this issue? Note that the test runs fine until the end, when this error appears.

I've pasted my file contents below, in the hope that it helps with finding a solution to this issue:

**package.json**

```
"devDependencies": {
    "json2csv": "^2.4.3",
    "protractor": "^2.1.0",
    "protractor-perf": "^0.1.8",
    "selenium-webdriver": "^2.46.1"
}
```

**protractor-config.js**

```
exports.config = {
    seleniumPort : 4444,
    seleniumServerJar: "./../../selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.46.0.jar",
    // Additional command line options to pass to selenium. For example,
    // if you need to change the browser timeout, use
    // seleniumArgs: ['-browserTimeout=60']
    // Ignored if seleniumServerJar is null.
    seleniumArgs: ["-Xmx=1024M"],
    capabilities : {
        browserName : 'chrome'
    },
    chromeDriver: "./../../selenium/chromedriver",
    specs : [ 'e2e/*-spec.js' ],
    framework : "jasmine2",
    // The timeout in milliseconds for each script run on the browser. This should
    // be longer than the maximum time your application needs to stabilize between
    // tasks.
    allScriptsTimeout: 11000,

    // How long to wait for a page to load.
    getPageTimeout: 10000
}
```

**ui-spec.js**

This is the test that fails. The failure happens at the end of the test.

```
afterAll(function() {
    // writes metrics to a file using Node
    exportMetrics();
});

describe("suite", function () {

    beforeEach(function(){
        browser.manage().deleteAllCookies();
    });

    afterEach(function() {
        perfRunner.getStats().then(function(stats) {
            // stores metrics for current test
            storeMetrics(stats, "test");
        });
    });

    it("test", function () {
        browser.get(test.url);
        perfRunner.start();

        var btnSales = $("span[icon='s_flat']");
        btnSales.click();

        var inputMin = element.all(by.css("input[data-testid='bfs-input-min']")).first();
        inputMin.clear();
        inputMin.sendKeys('1000');

        var inputMax = element.all(by.css("input[data-testid='bfs-input-max']")).first();
        inputMax.clear();
        inputMax.sendKeys('20000');

        var btnSearch = $("button[data-link-name='search-filtered']");
        btnSearch.click();

        var dropdownSort = element.all(by.css(".dropdown-selection")).first();
        browser.driver.wait(protractor.until.elementIsVisible(dropdownSort));
        dropdownSort.click();

        var sortOption = element.all(by.repeater("(key, item) in ::options")).get(2);
        browser.driver.wait(protractor.until.elementIsVisible(sortOption));
        sortOption.click();

        var btnDetails = element.all(by.css("a.btn-regular")).first();
        browser.driver.wait(protractor.until.elementIsVisible(btnDetails));
        btnDetails.click();

        perfRunner.stop();
    });

}
```

**stacktrace**

`Message:
    Failed: [log("performance")] Error response status: 13, , UnknownError - An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Selenium error: Java heap space
  Stack:
    Error: Failed: [log("performance")] Error response status: 13, , UnknownError - An unknown server-side error occurre
d while processing the command. Selenium error: Java heap space
        at C:\Test_Project\node_modules\protractor-perf\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasminewd2
\index.js:102:16
        at [object Object].promise.ControlFlow.runInFrame_ (C:\Test_Project\node_modules\protractor-per
f\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:1877:20)
        at [object Object].promise.Callback_.goog.defineClass.notify (C:\Test_Project\node_modules\prot
ractor-perf\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:2464:25)
        at [object Object].promise.Promise.notify_ (C:\Test_Project\node_modules\protractor-perf\node_m
odules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:563:12)
  Message:
    Failed: Cannot read property 'loadTime' of undefined
  Stack:
    Error: Failed: Cannot read property 'loadTime' of undefined
        at C:\Test_Project\node_modules\protractor-perf\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasminewd2
\index.js:102:16
        at [object Object].promise.ControlFlow.runInFrame_ (C:\Test_Project\node_modules\protractor-per
f\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:1877:20)
        at [object Object].promise.Callback_.goog.defineClass.notify (C:\Test_Project\node_modules\prot
ractor-perf\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:2464:25)
        at [object Object].promise.Promise.notify_ (C:\Test_Project\node_modules\protractor-perf\node_m
odules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:563:12)`

Comment: shouldn't it be `"-Xmx1024M"`? without `=`

Comment: @maurycy unfortunately, removing the '=' has no effect. I still receive the 'heap space' error.